OpenGL doesn't display anything when used with GTK?
I can display an interface with buttons in it but when using a GLArea, I can't seem to get it right:
#include "ui.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the color to red
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Draw a square
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);

    glEnd();
    glFlush();

        return TRUE;
}

int start_ui(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GObject *window;
        GError *error = NULL;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* Construct a GtkBuilder instance and load our UI description */
    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    if (gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.ui", &error) == 0) {
        g_printerr ("Error loading file: %s\n", error->message);
        g_clear_error (&error);
        return 1;
    }

        window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
        g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new ();
        g_signal_connect (gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}

I also have a builder.ui file:
<interface>
  <object id="window" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="title">Grid</property>
    <property name="border-width">10</property>
    <child>
      <object id="grid" class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <child>
          <object id="glarea" class="GtkGLArea">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="width-request">400</property>
        <property name="height-request">300</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left-attach">0</property>
        <property name="top-attach">1</property>
        <property name="width">4</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>

My problem is that the output is a black screen as such:

How can I fix this?

how do you create GL context? Is it single, or double buffered? Will GTK call swapBuffers for you automatically?

Please provide code which can be compiled and run, i.e. with main() function and required headers. In your code gl_area is not defined. Also builder.ui is not valid, one </child> tag is not in place and one </object> tag is missed.

My guess is that Vertices are specified CW instead of CCW.
